# File fails to save when filename is modified

Tags: java, swing, file, file-extension

I have a button that opens a save dialog window with default extension filters set, but when the user does not provide a file name extension on the file name, it should add the extension automatically. The problem is that when this happens the file will not save (or fail to save) but does not throw any exception. The file save successfully pop-up shows up telling the user that the file has been saved successfully but no file was found in the directory. Here's my code:

```
    private void saveRecordsButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                                  
    {                                                      
        if(evt.getSource() == this.saveRecordsButton)
        {
            String recordName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Please type in the name of the record you are about to export: ", "Input Notice", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            if(recordName == null || recordName.equals(""))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You must type in the name of the record in order to save!", "Input Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }

            int returnVal = this.fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
            {
                //ObjectOutput oos = null;
                try
                {
                    File file = this.fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    String recordDate = this.viewByDateCB.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    XMLTableProducer xmlTableProducer = new XMLTableProducer(this.cbtm, "Cash Book Table", recordName, recordDate, new Date());

                    if(!file.getName().contains("."))
                    {
                        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = (FileNameExtensionFilter)this.fileChooser.getFileFilter();
                        file = new File(file.getName()+(filter.getExtensions())[0]);
                        System.out.println(file.getName()); //This actually prints out the exact file name with extension the way I want
                    }

                    // if file doesnt exists, then create it
                    if(!file.exists()) 
                    {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }

                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw);
                    out.print(xmlTableProducer.getDynamicText());
                    out.close();
                    bw.close();

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "File Saved Successfully!", "Saved", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
                catch(IOException xcp)
                {
                    xcp.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: After you print the data (and before you close your writer), make sure you call `out.flush();`

Comment: @JoshM Assuming that nothing goes wrong with the write process, shouldn't `close` be flushing the output stream (personally, I'm paranoid, so I do both ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `file = new File(file.getName()+(filter.getExtensions())[0]);` is stripping the path of the `File`...

Let's say that the user choose to save the file in `C:\My Documents\Boss`.  When you as `File#getName` it will only return `Boss`.  Which now means that the file will be saved to the same location that the program is being executed from (ie `.\Bosss`)

Instead `file = new File(file.getName()+(filter.getExtensions())[0]);`, you should be using `file = new File(file.getPath()+(filter.getExtensions())[0]);` which return the "full" path and file name represented by the `File`

**Updated...**

Your file writing process is also a little off.

A general rule of thumb, if you open the stream, you should close it...

You shouldn't be closing the resources within the `try-catch`, if an `Exception` occurs within the `try-catch`, the `close` methods will never be called, leaving the resources open...

```
try
{
    /*...*/
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw);
    out.print(xmlTableProducer.getDynamicText());
    out.close();
    bw.close();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "File Saved Successfully!", "Saved", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
catch(IOException xcp)
{
    // If an exception occurs, the file will remain open
    xcp.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

Instead, you should use the `finally` block to try and close all your resources, for example...

```
BufferedWriter bw = null;
try
{
    /*...*/
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw);
    out.print(xmlTableProducer.getDynamicText());

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "File Saved Successfully!", "Saved", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
catch(IOException xcp)
{
    xcp.printStackTrace(System.err);
} finally {
    try 
    {
        bw.close();
    } 
    catch    (Exception exp) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you MadProgrammer, I have been highly educated by you.

Answer (score 2):

The code looks okay. Since you see no exception, I suspect  you are not looking at the correct directory. After

```
// if file doesn't exists, then create it
                        if(!file.exists()) 
                        {
                            file.createNewFile();
                        }
```

add

```
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Verify that the directory you are looking in to is the path shown there..

Comment: Thanks Zenil, I think you have opened my eyez a little bit. It saves the file to a different directory entirely from the selected directory. I am trying to understand why it happens that way, or do you have any idea? The selected directory is "C:\Users\Jevison7x\Documents\" while the target directory is "C:\Users\Jevison7x\Documents\NetBeansProjects\RoyalineApp\"

Comment: The JVM will save it to the directory where you run your java program from. This is known as the working directory. You can see it if you print System.getProperty("user.dir"); In your case since you run the program RoyalineApp directory, it saves the file there..This only happens when you donot specify the full file path